# adding dynamic locale prefix in Route Group

Tags: php, laravel, routes

i am trying to add dynamic locale prefix in Route Group, First of all i am getting ip address of a user through https://github.com/stevebauman/location this package and then comparing the locale with database and set the locale according to that and if it doesn't find the locale in database then i assign default locale and all these logic is done in **Web** group middleware which is allowed for all the urls. i have tried the following solution:

**LanguageMiddleware.php** it's a middleware which is assigned to all routes in the Web middlewaregroup.

```
$position = Location::get('109.219.245.57'); 
        
    $locale = Locale::where('country_code',strtolower($position->countryCode))->first();
    if($locale){
    //     // LaravelLocalization::setLocale($locale->country_code);
        session()->put('country_locale',$locale->country_code);
        session()->put('country_language',$locale->language);
        session()->put('default_locale',$locale->country_code);
        App::setLocale($locale->country_code);
 }
else{
        App::setLocale('en');
        session()->put('country_locale','en');
        session()->put('country_language','English');
        session()->put('default_locale','en');
    }
```

Everything is working fine till that and locale is changing as i want.

NOW, i want to have locale prefix for all the routes and i tried the following solutions:

**Solution 1** :

**web.php**

```
Route::group([
 'prefix' => app()->getLocale()   
], function(){
All of my routes goes here 
}
```

gives me the default locale 'en' on every route as [www.example.com/en](http://www.example.com/en)
when i try to change the locale through application then website is translated but the locale is still en in the route.

what am i doing wrong in it here. any help would be really appreciated.

thank you

Comment: side note: that prefix is always going to be hardcoded if you cache your routes  ... theses routes are registered before the middleware is ran, and you don't have a dynamic route parameter

Comment: this makes sense. appreciate your note. thank you